# Can dojo AMD constructor call the function defined by itself?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm new to dojo. I was trying to call a function from dojo class constructor, but the it complaints that the function called is undefined. Here is the code sample:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"
], function(declare) {
return declare(null, {
  MY_PROPERTY1: "property1";
  MY_PROPERTY2: "property2";

  constructor: function() {
    myFunction();
  }

  myFunction: function() {
    // dummy code;
  }
});
```

});

So my question is that it is possible to call the **myFunction** in the constructor? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `this.myFunction()?` You do realize you have not created a function called `myFunction`? You have a function that is attached to the `myFunction` property.

Comment: I have tried this.myFunction(), the same result. In firebug console, the error message is TypeError: this.myFunction is not a function.

Comment: @Xiaming It should work [according to the doc](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare) Does using `this.MY_PROPERTY` not work?

Comment: @Juan, I read the doc before asking this question, the property works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the `declare` function, one option is the following:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {    
  function myReusableFunction() {
      console.log('myReusableFunction');
  }
  return declare(null, {
    MY_PROPERTY1: "property1";
    MY_PROPERTY2: "property2";

    constructor: function() {
      myReusableFunction();
    },

    myFunction: function() {
      myReusableFunction();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: or this.myFunction(); in the constructor

Comment: @Juan, Your solution works pretty good.  Looks like the function should be defined before constructor?

Comment: To add on to this, you generally shouldn't need to call too many things inside the constructor function in dojo. There are other stages, buildRendering and postCreate, where things should usually get done.